# Extend keycloak token with custom data

Tags: java, keycloak

My project works as follows:

- Keycloak on the internal network for saving users
- A service that available externally and proxies and supplements requests to Keycloak.

Since the basic information in the token is not enough for me, I use a modified version of the plugin from [here](https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-tokenmapper-example) where some data that I load by user ID is added to my token in the setClaim method.

Everything was fine, but now I ran into a problem that when requesting `https://example.com/realms/realmname/protocol/openid-connect/token`
I need to pass some conditional parameters
`key1=value1&key2=value2`
in addition to the standard fields
`client_id=account&grant_type=password&username=example&password=example`
and somehow get access to them in the setClaim method.

Currently I emulate this behaviour by setting user attributes before requesting keycloak for token, but this decision is very bad because attributes remains on user forever and affects any next sessions.

I have no idea how to do this and haven't found any information on the internet.

Comment: you have to add custom claims and custom mapper

you can find this solution in this url

https://medium.com/@pavithbuddhima/how-to-add-custom-claims-to-jwt-tokens-from-an-external-source-in-keycloak-52bd1ff596d3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite an insecure usecase, if you are able to set a token claim when requesting the token itself.

The preferable solution would be

1. To pass the required parameter upon the authentication (e.g., `MyCustomAuthenticator`), and save them in the e.g., authentication session or client note.
2. You can add custom mappers (e.g., `MyCustomAuthSessionNoteMapper`) to various client scopes, and upon issuing the token, those mappers can add custom values as token claims.
3. Register your custom Authenticator and Mapper in the appropriate `src/main/resources/META-INF/services` file.

This way, the authentication process can validate the processed parameters and is also able to deny the authentication, in case the parameters are not valid.

```
public class MyCustomAuthenticator implements org.keycloak.authentication.Authenticator {

    @Override
    public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {

        String value1 = context.getAuthenticationSession().getClientNotes().get(AuthorizationEndpoint.LOGIN_SESSION_NOTE_ADDITIONAL_REQ_PARAMS_PREFIX + "key1")
        if (isValid(key1, value1)) {
            context.getAuthenticationSession().setAuthNote(("key1", value1);
        } else {
            // error handling
        }

        context.success();
    }
    
}

public class MyCustomAuthSessionNoteMapper extends AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper
        implements OIDCAccessTokenMapper, OIDCAccessTokenResponseMapper {
    
    @Override
    protected void setClaim(AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse, ProtocolMapperModel mappingModel,
        UserSessionModel userSession, KeycloakSession keycloakSession,
        ClientSessionContext clientSessionCtx) {

        String value1 = context.getAuthenticationSession().getAuthNote("key1");
        OIDCAttributeMapperHelper.mapClaim(accessTokenResponse, mappingModel, value1);

    }
    // other methods not shown

}
```